# Find If Two Strings are Permutations While Prioritizing Time/Long Strings/Short Strings

Tags: java, string, hashmap, permutation, xor

So I am trying to find the best implementation methods to find if two strings are permutations of each other for three cases: 1. for very long input strings, 2. for very long input strings and prioritizing speed, and 3. very short input strings and prioritizing space.

My implementation for the first case is using XOR:

```
if (string1.length() != string2.length())
    {
        return false;
    }
    int find = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < string1.length();i++ ){
        find ^= string1.charAt(i) ^ string2.charAt(i);
    }


    return find == 0;
```

My implementation for the second case is using a hash map or hash set which I haven't implemented yet.

My implementation for the last one is sorting the strings and using java .equals to compare if the strings are equal.

```
if (string1.length() != string2.length()) {
        return false;
    }
    char[] a = string1.toCharArray();
    char[] b = string2.toCharArray();

    Arrays.sort(a);
    Arrays.sort(b);

    return Arrays.equals(a, b);
```

** Test input: 2 empty Strings; "ab" "ba"; "abc" "acd"; "*rats*" "star**"; "\u263A BYE NOW!!" "!BYE NOW! \u263A"

Would these three implementations be best for these cases?

Comment: @azurefrog it's not a try and see if it works type thing. They all work, it is a question about if those are the best implementations for those cases.

Comment: You'll want to define space too, memory or storage?

Comment: @jrtapsell memory but examples of either would be beneficial

Comment: Depends on the code. Your question is not specific enough to make a determination.

Comment: What do you mean by best? Elapsed time? The easiest way to test which of several implementations is most efficient is to test them with various data sets.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: "XOR", "hash map", and "hash set" are not algorithms for testing the equivalence of permuted strings.  You should show how your code _uses_ those things if you want any meaningful opinions.  (But then, you still might get down voted for asking an opinion-based question.)  Also, strings of what?  The "best" solution could depend on both the size of the character set, and maybe also on the relative frequencies with which the different characters appear.

Comment: @jameslarge I literally said USING and also described the relative size of each data set. I'm not looking for specifics for a certain set of data. This is all general use cases.

Comment: @sprinter best is not referring to time. It is referring to the general cases I have described. What implementations would be optimal for data sets with large input strings or short input strings.

Comment: @Jack I'm still not sure what 'best' or 'optimal' means for you. For me, 'best' means maximum code clarity, readability, maintainability. Most code does not need to be optimised for performance. And when it does, you need to choose a balance of CPU, IO, memory, network that you want to optimise for. Just saying 'best' or 'optimal' is way too vague to get a useful answer.

Comment: @Jack, "_Using_ XOR" is not an algorithm either.  But the code examples that you have since added to your question are algorithms.  That gives people something to comment on.  Unfortunately, your first algorithm (the XOR one) can give false positives.  For example, try it with string1 == "ABA" and string2 == "BCC".